# Динамически добавить XAML при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: wpf, mvvm

В моем приложении в пользователь решает сколько переменных ему нужно (от 0 до 15). В соответствии с его выбором в UserControl должно появиться столько Grid с отдельными элементами в нем, сколько выбрал пользователь. Как реализовать это динамическое подтягивание ?

Comment: Используйте ItemsControl и шаблоны

Comment: А к чему привязывать ItemsControl?

Comment: К массиву с переменными. Вы ведь их где-то храните?

Comment: в XAML их к чему привязать?

Comment: Я вас не понимаю, у вас должен быть массив с переменными и из XAML вы привязываетесь к нему: `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyVariables}" ...`

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ помог мне.

Comment: Оформите решение ответом, чтобы топик не висел открытым